# Design of a controller

Tags: control, control-system, motor-controller, pid-controller

I am working on a project that requires me to design a controller knowing the following specifications:

*"The controller performance must be consistent under varying conditions. The rotor must respond rapidly as it moves in small steps of unity. For each step, the controller must get the rotor position to within 2% of its final value in less than 1s and must eventually reach unity. During your research, you found out that packaging would get damaged if the base position exceeds 6% of the final value with this quick response. In addition, if the operator enters a unity sloped linearly increasing input then the output must eventually track the input and be at most 0.1 degrees away."*

From the previous paragraph I can deduce that:

damping ratio = 0.667

natural frequency = 5.996 rad/s

damped natural frequency = 4.47 rad/s

damping ratio x natural frequency = 4 rad/s

I tried two types of solutions for this problem: **the PID controller** and the **Lead-Lag Compensator** and I'm stuck at both and don't know how to continue.

**For the PID controller**:
I tried the following code on MATLAB which gives me all the specifications required for a unit step input (settling time under 1 sec, maximum overshoot doesn't exceed 6%, and reaches unity at steady state.) However, I cannot only follow this since I still have to show mathematical calculations that would lead me to the results I got on MATLAB. (Also, I still haven't used the fact that it is 0.1 degrees away at ramp input, I have no idea where to use this.)

> num = [1 1]
>
> den = [1 10 9 19]
>
> Gp = tf(num,den)
>
> H = [1]
>
> s = tf('s')
>
> CL = feedback(Gp,H)
>
> step(CL)
>
> hold on
>
> %%
>
> Kp = 600
>
> Ki = 1
>
> Kd = 50 %killing the overshoot
>
> Gc = pid(Kp,Ki,Kd)
>
> CL_control = feedback(Gc*Gp, H)
>
> step(CL_control)
>
> grid on

How can I mathematically design a PID controller from what I got on MATLAB?

**For the Lead-Lag compensator**: I tried different ways to design this compensator mainly from the book *Katsuhiko Ogata-Modern Control Engineering (5th Edition) -Prentice Hall (2009)* and other methods I have found on the internet. But it seems that every time I come up with the result, the root locus of the new system doesn't go through my new desired points ( s = -4 + 4.47j ) and I'm having problems in getting the static velocity error constant Kv.

The new root locus is NOT going through my desired points, I want to know why and how can I fix it.

*Further info:*
We're dealing with a unity feedback loop.
The following is the transfer function of the plant:

\$\ \frac{s + 1}{s^3 + 10s^2 + 9s + 19}\$

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific question. Hit the edit link ...

Comment: @Transistor done

Comment: What are you trying to control? 'Rotor' is a bit vague. I'm guessing angle of the rotor blades. Generally, for PID control, start with a relatively large value of Integral gain c.f. the proportional gain, and no differential term. Back-off the integral gain until stable and speed of response is acceptable. Add a little derivative if necessary to damp down oscillations. The Ziegler-Nichols method is a waste of time, btw.

Comment: @Chu I did exactly what you said, can I prove it mathematically though? Not through MATLAB?

Comment: It's difficult to 'prove' a procedure mathematically. I suppose there's an argument for using as little derivative as possible, due to adverse noise effects.

Comment: @Chu So is there no hope to determine the integral time and the derivative time (Ti and Td) for the PID controller (as well as the proportional gain Kp) without running simulations? And for the lead lag compensator how can I find the required poles and zeroes?